# RabbitMQ PHP (pecl php-amqp) reading takes more then 1.5 second (during a small benchmark)

Tags: php, rabbitmq, php-amqp

We have a test running with RabbitMQ, but somehow hit a "threshold" which makes RabbitMQ slow.

What we did, we setup a RabbitMQ server and made a small PHP script that uses pecl-amqp to connect (no pconnect) to the MQ server, sends 1 random message and disconnects immediately after that.
We fork this process 200 times (single php execution, so no threading), which means every second +/- 2000 connections are opened to the MQ server and closed.

After that I start the same script on a different server to measure the connect time + read time.
We noticed that it takes +/- 1.5 seconds until the "Connection.Start" message  is received by the client.
I've added a screenshot of the tcpdump for this single client to show you the situation. Another problem we see, there are a lot of TCP Out-Of-Order and Retransmissions.

**Server specs**

- Bare Metal
- CPU: 2x Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2420 0 @ 1.90GHz
- Memory: 24GB

**TCPdump**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1UoM.png

**sysctl settings:**

```
fs.file-max = 11479756
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 10
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 4096
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 30
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 9
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 7200
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=1

net.core.somaxconn=2048
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 10240    65535
net.nf_conntrack_max = 1000000
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_ignore = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_announce = 2
```

**rabbitmq.conf**

```
%% -*- mode: erlang -*-
[{
        rabbit,
        [{
                tcp_listeners, [{
                    "10.0.1.69", 5672
                }, {
                    "::1", 5672
                }]
            },
                {tcp_listen_options, [binary,
                {packet, raw},
                {reuseaddr, true},
                {backlog, 65535},
                {nodelay, true},
                {exit_on_close, false},
                {keepalive, true},
                {sndbuf, 32768},
                {recbuf,32768}]
            },

            { vm_memory_high_watermark,  0.6  },

            {
                log_levels,
                [{
                    connection,
                    debug
                }, {
                    channel,
                    debug
                }]
            },

            {
                loopback_users,
                []
            },

            {
                default_user,
                << "code_mucRfHX79xvil" >>
            }, {
                default_pass,
                << "xxxx" >>
            }
        ]
    },

    {
        kernel,
        [{
            inet_default_connect_options,
            [{
                nodelay,
                true
            }]
        }, {
            inet_default_listen_options,
            [{
                nodelay,
                true
            }]
        }]
    },

    {
        rabbitmq_management,
        []
    },

    {
        rabbitmq_shovel,
        [{
            shovels,
            []
        }]
    },

    {
        rabbitmq_stomp,
        []
    },

    {
        rabbitmq_mqtt,
        [{
            default_user,
            << "code_mucRfHX79xvil" >>
        }, {
            default_pass,
            << "xxxxx" >>
        }]
    },

    {
        rabbitmq_amqp1_0,
        [{
            default_user,
            << "code_mucRfHX79xvil" >>
        }]
    },

    {
        rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap,
        []
    }
].
```

**rabbitmqctl report (during "heavy" load test)**

```
Reporting server status on {{2015,12,29},{14,43,15}}

 ...
Status of node rabbit@web1 ...
[{pid,7730},
 {running_applications,
     [{rabbitmq_shovel_management,"Shovel Status","3.6.0"},
      {rabbitmq_management,"RabbitMQ Management Console","3.6.0"},
      {rabbitmq_web_dispatch,"RabbitMQ Web Dispatcher","3.6.0"},
      {webmachine,"webmachine","git"},
      {mochiweb,"MochiMedia Web Server","2.13.0"},
      {rabbitmq_shovel,"Data Shovel for RabbitMQ","3.6.0"},
      {rabbitmq_management_agent,"RabbitMQ Management Agent","3.6.0"},
      {rabbit,"RabbitMQ","3.6.0"},
      {os_mon,"CPO  CXC 138 46","2.2.14"},
      {ssl,"Erlang/OTP SSL application","5.3.2"},
      {public_key,"Public key infrastructure","0.21"},
      {crypto,"CRYPTO version 2","3.2"},
      {amqp_client,"RabbitMQ AMQP Client","3.6.0"},
      {rabbit_common,[],"3.6.0"},
      {inets,"INETS  CXC 138 49","5.9.7"},
      {mnesia,"MNESIA  CXC 138 12","4.11"},
      {compiler,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","4.9.4"},
      {xmerl,"XML parser","1.3.5"},
      {syntax_tools,"Syntax tools","1.6.12"},
      {asn1,"The Erlang ASN1 compiler version 2.0.4","2.0.4"},
      {ranch,"Socket acceptor pool for TCP protocols.","1.2.1"},
      {sasl,"SASL  CXC 138 11","2.3.4"},
      {stdlib,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","1.19.4"},
      {kernel,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","2.16.4"}]},
 {os,{unix,linux}},
 {erlang_version,
     "Erlang R16B03 (erts-5.10.4) [source] [64-bit] [smp:24:24] [async-threads:64] [kernel-poll:true]\n"},
 {memory,
     [{total,74421680},
      {connection_readers,0},
      {connection_writers,0},
      {connection_channels,0},
      {connection_other,2704},
      {queue_procs,2704},
      {queue_slave_procs,0},
      {plugins,1630200},
      {other_proc,20907680},
      {mnesia,61736},
      {mgmt_db,1294648},
      {msg_index,53056},
      {other_ets,1387864},
      {binary,8651592},
      {code,26770847},
      {atom,951441},
      {other_system,12707208}]},
 {alarms,[]},
 {listeners,
     [{clustering,25672,"::"},{amqp,5672,"10.0.1.69"},{amqp,5672,"::1"}]},
 {vm_memory_high_watermark,0.6},
 {vm_memory_limit,15139282944},
 {disk_free_limit,50000000},
 {disk_free,34608447488},
 {file_descriptors,
     [{total_limit,65435},
      {total_used,8},
      {sockets_limit,58889},
      {sockets_used,6}]},
 {processes,[{limit,1048576},{used,276}]},
 {run_queue,2},
 {uptime,3756},
 {kernel,{net_ticktime,60}}]

Cluster status of node rabbit@web1 ...
[{nodes,[{disc,[rabbit@web1]}]},
 {running_nodes,[rabbit@web1]},
 {cluster_name,<<"rabbit@web1.company.net">>},
 {partitions,[]}]

Application environment of node rabbit@web1 ...
[{amqp_client,[{prefer_ipv6,false},{ssl_options,[]}]},
 {asn1,[]},
 {compiler,[]},
 {crypto,[]},
 {inets,[]},
 {kernel,
     [{error_logger,tty},
      {inet_default_connect_options,[{nodelay,true}]},
      {inet_default_listen_options,[{nodelay,true}]},
      {inet_dist_listen_max,25672},
      {inet_dist_listen_min,25672}]},
 {mnesia,[{dir,"/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@web1"}]},
 {mochiweb,[]},
 {os_mon,
     [{start_cpu_sup,false},
      {start_disksup,false},
      {start_memsup,false},
      {start_os_sup,false}]},
 {public_key,[]},
 {rabbit,
     [{auth_backends,[rabbit_auth_backend_internal]},
      {auth_mechanisms,['PLAIN','AMQPLAIN']},
      {backing_queue_module,rabbit_priority_queue},
      {channel_max,0},
      {cluster_keepalive_interval,10000},
      {cluster_nodes,{[],disc}},
      {cluster_partition_handling,ignore},
      {collect_statistics,fine},
      {collect_statistics_interval,5000},
      {credit_flow_default_credit,{200,50}},
      {default_permissions,[<<".*">>,<<".*">>,<<".*">>]},
      {default_user,<<"username">>},
      {default_user_tags,[administrator]},
      {default_vhost,<<"/">>},
      {delegate_count,16},
      {disk_free_limit,50000000},
      {enabled_plugins_file,"/etc/rabbitmq/enabled_plugins"},
      {error_logger,{file,"/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@web1.log"}},
      {fhc_read_buffering,false},
      {fhc_write_buffering,true},
      {frame_max,131072},
      {halt_on_upgrade_failure,true},
      {handshake_timeout,10000},
      {heartbeat,60},
      {hipe_compile,false},
      {hipe_modules,
          [rabbit_reader,rabbit_channel,gen_server2,rabbit_exchange,
           rabbit_command_assembler,rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1,rabbit_basic,
           rabbit_event,lists,queue,priority_queue,rabbit_router,rabbit_trace,
           rabbit_misc,rabbit_binary_parser,rabbit_exchange_type_direct,
           rabbit_guid,rabbit_net,rabbit_amqqueue_process,
           rabbit_variable_queue,rabbit_binary_generator,rabbit_writer,
           delegate,gb_sets,lqueue,sets,orddict,rabbit_amqqueue,
           rabbit_limiter,gb_trees,rabbit_queue_index,
           rabbit_exchange_decorator,gen,dict,ordsets,file_handle_cache,
           rabbit_msg_store,array,rabbit_msg_store_ets_index,rabbit_msg_file,
           rabbit_exchange_type_fanout,rabbit_exchange_type_topic,mnesia,
           mnesia_lib,rpc,mnesia_tm,qlc,sofs,proplists,credit_flow,pmon,
           ssl_connection,tls_connection,ssl_record,tls_record,gen_fsm,ssl]},
      {log_levels,[{connection,debug},{channel,debug}]},
      {loopback_users,[]},
      {memory_monitor_interval,2500},
      {mirroring_flow_control,true},
      {mirroring_sync_batch_size,4096},
      {mnesia_table_loading_timeout,30000},
      {msg_store_credit_disc_bound,{2000,500}},
      {msg_store_file_size_limit,16777216},
      {msg_store_index_module,rabbit_msg_store_ets_index},
      {msg_store_io_batch_size,2048},
      {password_hashing_module,rabbit_password_hashing_sha256},
      {plugins_dir,"/usr/lib/rabbitmq/lib/rabbitmq_server-3.6.0/plugins"},
      {plugins_expand_dir,
          "/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@web1-plugins-expand"},
      {queue_index_embed_msgs_below,4096},
      {queue_index_max_journal_entries,32768},
      {reverse_dns_lookups,false},
      {sasl_error_logger,{file,"/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@web1-sasl.log"}},
      {server_properties,[]},
      {ssl_allow_poodle_attack,false},
      {ssl_apps,[asn1,crypto,public_key,ssl]},
      {ssl_cert_login_from,distinguished_name},
      {ssl_handshake_timeout,5000},
      {ssl_listeners,[]},
      {ssl_options,[]},
      {tcp_listen_options,
          [binary,
           {packet,raw},
           {reuseaddr,true},
           {backlog,65535},
           {nodelay,true},
           {exit_on_close,false},
           {keepalive,true},
           {sndbuf,32768},
           {recbuf,32768}]},
      {tcp_listeners,[{"10.0.1.69",5672},{"::1",5672}]},
      {trace_vhosts,[]},
      {vm_memory_high_watermark,0.6},
      {vm_memory_high_watermark_paging_ratio,0.5}]},
 {rabbit_common,[]},
 {rabbitmq_management,
     [{http_log_dir,none},
      {listener,[{port,15672}]},
      {load_definitions,none},
      {rates_mode,basic},
      {sample_retention_policies,
          [{global,[{605,5},{3660,60},{29400,600},{86400,1800}]},
           {basic,[{605,5},{3600,60}]},
           {detailed,[{10,5}]}]}]},
 {rabbitmq_management_agent,[]},
 {rabbitmq_shovel,
     [{defaults,
          [{prefetch_count,1000},
           {ack_mode,on_confirm},
           {publish_fields,[]},
           {publish_properties,[]},
           {reconnect_delay,5}]},
      {shovels,[]}]},
 {rabbitmq_shovel_management,[]},
 {rabbitmq_web_dispatch,[]},
 {ranch,[]},
 {sasl,[{errlog_type,error},{sasl_error_logger,false}]},
 {ssl,[]},
 {stdlib,[]},
 {syntax_tools,[]},
 {webmachine,[{error_handler,rabbit_webmachine_error_handler}]},
 {xmerl,[]}]

Connections:
pid name    port    peer_port   host    peer_host   ssl peer_cert_subject   peer_cert_issuer    peer_cert_validity  auth_mechanism  ssl_protocol    ssl_key_exchange    ssl_cipher  ssl_hash    protocol    user    vhost   timeout frame_max   channel_max client_properties   connected_at    recv_oct    recv_cnt    send_oct    send_cnt    send_pend   state   channels
<rabbit@web1.2.2507.1349>   10.0.1.210:23801 -> 10.0.1.69:5672  5672    23801   10.0.1.69   10.0.1.210  false               PLAIN                   {0,9,1} username    /   0   131072  256 [{"product","rabbitmq-c"},{"version","0.5.2"},{"platform","Linux-3.2.0-37-generic"},{"copyright","Copyright (c) 2007-2014 VMWare Inc, Tony Garnock-Jones, and Alan Antonuk."},{"information","See https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c"},{"client",[{"type","php-amqp extension"},{"version","1.6.1"},{"revision","release"},{"connection type","transient"},{"connection started","Tue, 29 Dec 2015 14:43:13 GMT"}]}]  1451400195480   542 5   530 4   0   running 1
<rabbit@web1.2.5625.1350>   10.0.1.210:44872 -> 10.0.1.69:5672  5672    44872   10.0.1.69   10.0.1.210  false               none                    {0,9,1}     none    3   4096    undefined   none    1451400195483   8   1   481 1   0   starting    0
<rabbit@web1.2.22878.1350>  10.0.1.210:22339 -> 10.0.1.69:5672  5672    22339   10.0.1.69   10.0.1.210  false               PLAIN                   {0,9,1} username    /   0   131072  256 [{"product","rabbitmq-c"},{"version","0.5.2"},{"platform","Linux-3.2.0-37-generic"},{"copyright","Copyright (c) 2007-2014 VMWare Inc, Tony Garnock-Jones, and Alan Antonuk."},{"information","See https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c"},{"client",[{"type","php-amqp extension"},{"version","1.6.1"},{"revision","release"},{"connection type","transient"},{"connection started","Tue, 29 Dec 2015 14:43:13 GMT"}]}]  1451400195480   651 7   554 6   0   running 1
<rabbit@web1.2.23697.1350>  10.0.1.210:23806 -> 10.0.1.69:5672  5672    23806   10.0.1.69   10.0.1.210  false               PLAIN                   {0,9,1} username    /   0   131072  256 [{"product","rabbitmq-c"},{"version","0.5.2"},{"platform","Linux-3.2.0-37-generic"},{"copyright","Copyright (c) 2007-2014 VMWare Inc, Tony Garnock-Jones, and Alan Antonuk."},{"information","See https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c"},{"client",[{"type","php-amqp extension"},{"version","1.6.1"},{"revision","release"},{"connection type","transient"},{"connection started","Tue, 29 Dec 2015 14:43:13 GMT"}]}]  1451400195482   510 3   514 3   0   running 0
<rabbit@web1.2.23763.1350>  10.0.1.210:23990 -> 10.0.1.69:5672  5672    23990   10.0.1.69   10.0.1.210  false               PLAIN                   {0,9,1} username    /   0   131072  256 [{"product","rabbitmq-c"},{"version","0.5.2"},{"platform","Linux-3.2.0-37-generic"},{"copyright","Copyright (c) 2007-2014 VMWare Inc, Tony Garnock-Jones, and Alan Antonuk."},{"information","See https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c"},{"client",[{"type","php-amqp extension"},{"version","1.6.1"},{"revision","release"},{"connection type","transient"},{"connection started","Tue, 29 Dec 2015 14:43:13 GMT"}]}]  1451400195482   510 4   514 3   0   running 0
<rabbit@web1.2.23786.1350>  10.0.1.210:22506 -> 10.0.1.69:5672  5672    22506   10.0.1.69   10.0.1.210  false               PLAIN                   {0,9,1} username    /   0   131072  256 [{"product","rabbitmq-c"},{"version","0.5.2"},{"platform","Linux-3.2.0-37-generic"},{"copyright","Copyright (c) 2007-2014 VMWare Inc, Tony Garnock-Jones, and Alan Antonuk."},{"information","See https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c"},{"client",[{"type","php-amqp extension"},{"version","1.6.1"},{"revision","release"},{"connection type","transient"},{"connection started","Tue, 29 Dec 2015 14:43:13 GMT"}]}]  1451400195481   510 3   514 3   0   running 0

Channels:
pid name    connection  number  user    vhost   transactional   confirm consumer_count  messages_unacknowledged messages_unconfirmed    messages_uncommitted    acks_uncommitted    prefetch_count  global_prefetch_count   state
<rabbit@web1.2.23553.1350>  10.0.1.210:23811 -> 10.0.1.69:5672 (1)  <rabbit@web1.2.23671.1350>  1   username    /   false   false   0   0   0   0   0   3   0   running

Queues on /:

Exchanges on /:
name    type    durable auto_delete internal    arguments   policy
    direct  true    false   false   []  
ack topic   false   false   false   []  
amq.direct  direct  true    false   false   []  
amq.fanout  fanout  true    false   false   []  
amq.headers headers true    false   false   []  
amq.match   headers true    false   false   []  
amq.rabbitmq.log    topic   true    false   true    []  
amq.rabbitmq.trace  topic   true    false   true    []  
amq.topic   topic   true    false   false   []  
direct  direct  false   false   false   []  

Bindings on /:

Consumers on /:

Permissions on /:
user    configure   write   read
username    .*  .*  .*

Policies on /:

Parameters on /:
```

**php code**

```
<?php
$connection = new AMQPConnection([
    'host' => 'host',
    'port' => 5672,
    'login' => 'username',
    'password' => 'password',
]);

$connection->connect();

$channel = new AMQPChannel($connection);
$exchange = new AMQPExchange($channel);
$exchange->setName('ack');
$exchange->setType(AMQP_EX_TYPE_TOPIC);
$exchange->declareExchange();
echo $exchange->publish('test data ' . mt_rand(1,100), 'ack.call');

$connection->disconnect();
```

Comment: Hi! php-amqp contributor here (I'm @pinepain on github). From what you posted I see that you are on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and use RabbitMQ 3.6.0, rabbitmq-c 0.5.2 and php-amqp 1.6.1. Can you please try to update to the latest versions (rabbitmq-c 0.7.1 or even build it from master and to php-amqp 1.7.0alpha2 or better to my branch from this PR - https://github.com/pdezwart/php-amqp/pull/194). At least after this point we may start investigating further problems deeper.

Comment: If it an option for you, try to reproduce the behavior on more recent Ubuntu distro, say, 15.10. Also, what about trying some older RabbitMQ version? Maybe it is worth to post a link to this question in [rabbitmq official user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users)?

Comment: Hi @zaq178miami I'am the colleague of alitrix,
thanks for you reply!
Currently I have build rabbitmq-c from master and php-amp from your repository using fix_stalled_connection_resource.
We run ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS with latest rabbitMq.
With this upgrade we've seen an improvement but still odd behaviour.
The publishes increase themselves to around 1200-1300 p/s and if we spawn more threads it just gets slower per request instead of processing more requests.

Comment: Hi @zaq178miami like my collegue mentioned, we see a small improvement, but still there is a delay of 800ms-1sec.
See screenshot of a tcpdump http://i.imgur.com/SKw1wTk.png
The issue is again, Connection.Start takes a long time to respond

Comment: Screenshot of my phpinfo with version numbers: http://i.imgur.com/5dwKqkq.png

Comment: I'm stuck a bit with that TCP dup acks and out-of-order, and especially with having `tcp_tw_reuse,recycle = 1`. Looks like complete mess in connections. I'm not sure it is safe to have them set to 1, check [Networking and RabbitMQ, OS Level Tuning section](https://www.rabbitmq.com/networking.html#os-tuning) RabbitMQ official doc. Meanwhile, can you try to run with `tcp_tw_{reuse,recycle} = 0` to check whether problem gone which impact it has on performance. Note, that there are [Flow Control](https://www.rabbitmq.com/flow-control.html) which when hit (may) have negative impact on throughput.

Comment: At this point it would be cool to hear from RabbitMQ staff or more experienced developers about sysctl settings you have from AMQP protocol and especially from RabbitMQ internals point if view.

Comment: Link to further discussion in rabbitmq-users group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-users/xmC4erXqMJI